# Google Sheet REGEXMATCH function case insensitive

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using below formula:

=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A2:A),"",IFERROR(if(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "ABC|PQR|XYZ"),"Yes","No"),"Not Found")))

Its giving correct result but is case sensitive, how to make this formula case insensitive.  Below is the link of the sheet:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/164kxDO9aWZzr5qXjvtRlk_tiRoKU1W7Xc-Ig9VH8qzE/edit#gid=1474753063

Regards

Comment: Or you can use (?i) before your regex =ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A2:A),"",IFERROR(if(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "(?i)abc|pqr|xyz"),"Yes","No"),"Not Found")))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some case conversion function. Try-

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A2:A),"",IFERROR(if(REGEXMATCH(UPPER(A2:A), "ABC|PQR|XYZ"),"Yes","No"),"Not Found")))
```