# Fill rows when a value is not in a column in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to create a list from a column when the cell doesn't contain a given text.

[image]

In the example above I want to exclude the folders that have the words (Archive, Rollback, rollback) as below.
[image]

I know

```
=countif(B2:B20,"<>*Archive*")
```

gives us the count but doesn't allow me to define more than one search phrase and also doesn't give a list.

Is it possible to use an Array Formula? where `=ARRAYFORMULA(B2:B20)` can be changed to exclude the words in B22

Test Sheet is in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WnGEsuuJcKsHVhpyYCX5EpmIxuKQEst5XVXgeETzxJ4/edit?pli=1#gid=1789577026

See the 'List_Excluding_Words' worksheet and feel free to add a worksheet with possible solutions.

Would a regex method work in this case like? [Google Sheet REGEXMATCH function case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67467333/google-sheet-regexmatch-function-case-insensitive)

I understand this can be done using filters but I want a full list so I can run other processes on it and it doesn't allow for more than one phrase.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B26 on the tab 'JPV_HELP' I entered

```
=filter(B2:B20, not(regexmatch(B2:B20, "(?i)Archive|Rollback")))
```

See if that works for you?